# Why are consistently balanced trees hard to implement and use in the "real world"?

Tags: tree

I'm taking a Algorithms and Data Structures course and one the the slides informs that "consistently balanced trees are hard to implement" and quotes the following phrase:

> “The difficulty of implementing balanced trees greatly restricts their
> use; balanced trees are rarely implemented except as part of a
> programming assignment in a data structures class.”
>
> -- W. Pugh

Is it true that these data structures are rarely implemented in the real world?

Using and applying balanced trees doesn't seem to be hard - then what am I missing?

I would like to know examples of difficulties that can be experienced in real applications that make balanced trees hard to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Balanced trees are hard to get right if you don't have a lot of experience in designing data structures, or can't look  up the details in a text book. Most people will never implement trees from scratch.

Despite that, balanced trees are very popular, because for most programming environments you can find a library that implements them. Some languages even have them in the standard library.

Comment: You are right. Actually, I misunderstood the statement: I interpreted "implemented" as "used", whereas it just means that people don't do it from scratch.